# Предикатив выражение "Под силу"

Tags: предикатив

Добрый вечер. Подскажите пожалуйста как доходчиво и понятно объяснить, что такое предикатив? Выражение "Под силу", "Не под силу". Человек выучил,что предлог "Под" соответствует творительному падежу. Я как мог объяснил,что здесь нужен именно винительный. Но я не могу объяснить это правило. Честно говоря,я сам его не очень понял.

Comment: _Человек выучил,что предлог "Под" соответствует творительному падежу._ === Покажите ему это: http://upravlenie.academic.ru/2503

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку. Я обязательно покажу. Но сначала нужно объяснить что такое предикатив. И если можно,доступным языком без сложных терминов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Человек выучил,что предлог "Под" соответствует творительному падежу.

Предлог ***под*** употребляется и [**с винительным падежом.**](http://upravlenie.academic.ru/2503)

> ...как доходчиво и понятно объяснить, что такое предикатив? Выражение
>   "Под силу", "Не под силу".

Предикативами, бывает, называют *слова состояния* — слова, выражающие значение бессубъектного состояния, выполняющие синтаксическую функцию сказуемого обычно в безличном предложении.

Примеры таких слов: *На улице **дождливо**.  В комнате стало **уютно**.*

**Но это не Ваш случай.**

> **Этот термин употребляют и в более широком значении** — для обозначения
>   всех неглагольных слов и связных словосочетаний, функционирующих как
>   сказуемое не только в односоставных безличных предложениях (типа
>   *совестно, дождливо*), но и в двусоставных (типа *рад, готов, горазд,* а также *в самый раз, в силах, под стать*).
>
> ***Панова Г.И. Морфология русского языка. Энциклопедический словарь-справочник. М., 2010.***

Именно в таком значении  этот термин употреблён и у Ефремовой, назвавшей предикативами сочетания [***"Под силу"***](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/216537), [***"Не под силу"***](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/193282), выполняющие **функцию сказуемого** в двусоставных предложениях.

Примеры употребления этих сочетаний:

***Эта задача ему под силу.***  Подлежащее —  ***задача;*** сказуемое — ***под силу.***

*Бабка начала укладывать поленницу. **Но эта работа была ей не под силу.***

Подлежащее —  ***работа;*** сказуемое — *была **не под силу.***

Answer (score 3):

> Предикатив — слова, обозначающие статическое состояние и выступающие в
>   функции сказуемого (предиката) безличного предложения.

Дальше пробуем рассказывать на примерах - от Грамоты.ру:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Подробнее](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2):

> Термин «предикатив» (категория состояния, безлично-предикативные
>   слова, слова состояния, предикативные слова, предикативные наречия)
>   был введён чешскими лингвистами во второй половине XX века и
>   применялся к той группе слов, которая в русской лингвистической
>   литературе ранее получила название «категория состояния».
>
> К предикативам относятся слова (или, реже, формы слов) разных частей
>   речи, но не во всех своих лексических значениях, а только в тех из
>   них, которые закреплены за употреблением этих слов в функции
>   сказуемого. Категория состояния некоторыми лингвистами рассматривается
>   как особая часть речи.
>
> Любое составное сказуемое (то есть выраженное не просто одним
>   глаголом) состоит из глагола-связки и предикативной части в виде
>   имени, инфинитива или слова состояния.

---

Теперь о [ПРЕДЛОГЕ «ПОД»](https://www.lingq.com/ru/learn/ru/preview/item/319977/)...

Предлог «под» используется с винительным и творительным падежами.

С винительным падежом он используется:

1. При движении ниже предмета:

Собака залезла под стол.

Книга упала под диван.

2. Со значением приблизительно, около:

Дело было под вечер.

Ей уже под сорок лет.

3. Действие под сопровождение чего-то:

Мы писали упражнение под диктовку учителя.

Они танцевали под музыку с диска.

4. При имитации чего-то:

Кольцо под золото (значит: оно не золотое, а только похоже на золото)

С творительным падежом «под» используется:

1. При нахождении под чем-то, ниже предмета:

Собака сидела под столом.

Ручка лежала под диваном.

2. При указании причины или следствия:

Она была под его большим влиянием.

Он находился под арестом уже два дня.

3. При указании местности:

Под Москвой

Под Парижем

Битва под Полтавой.

4. В некоторых кулинарных рецептах:

Яйцо под майонезом

Рыба под томатным соусом.